# My Qwest router appears to not save configuration changes. How can I fix this?

Tags: router

I have a Qwest router. Specifically, I have the Actiontec Q1000.

When I go to the configuration page, I can navigate fine, but whenever I submit a configuration change, it refuses to save. It says "saving changes" but when the page refreshes, nothing has actually changed.

How can I save changes to this router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Internet Explorer, and turn on compatibility mode.

Unfortunately the interface that this router uses is designed for super old browsers (i.e. IE6). This is why it doesn't work in Firefox. So if you use IE, you should be able to save. Turning on compatibility mode fixes a few additional things (like the reboot dialog).